# How to calculate "X-TIMESTAMP-MAP=LOCAL:00:00:00.000,MPEGTS:XXXXXX" MPEGTS value in WebVtt file?

Tags: c#, ios, hlsl, subtitle, webvtt

I'm using hls to stream a video while using in safari the subtitle's are not in a sync so added the time stamp map but not able to get the MPEGTS value for the web vtt file

How to calculate MPEGTS Value

Answer (score 2):

ffprobe -show_frames seg.ts should give you the right pkt_pts value